# DotVVM - Multiselect content is overlayed by input

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, multi-select, dotvvm

I have a problem with DotVVM multiselect styling. Content of multiselect is overlayed by input and I dont know what cause this problem. When I use `dropdown list` which uses exactly the same css classes, there isn't any problem with this. You can see dropdown list structure in picture below

Here is my HTML structure

```
<div class="form-group">
    <Label>
        <dot:Literal Text="{{value: Article.Article_Sections}}" />
    </Label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <bp:MultiSelect DataSource="{value: ArticleSectionsList}"
                        SelectedValues="{value: SelectedArticleSections}"
                        ItemTextBinding="{{value: Name}}"
                        ItemKeyBinding="{{value: Id}}"
                        class="form-control " />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <Label>
        <dot:Literal Text="{{value: DetailDTO.Name}}" />
    </Label>
    <div class="input-group" Validator.Value="{{value: DetailDTO.Name}}">
        <dot:TextBox class="form-control" Text="{{value: DetailDTO.Name}}" />

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code here

```
.form-group {
    position: relative;
}

.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

.dotvvm-bp-multi-select .bp-popup {
    display: none;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 1px;
    z-index: 1001;
    text-align: left;
}
//here is css for opened state
.dotvvm-bp-multi-select .bp-popup.bp-state-opened {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.dotvvm-bp-multi-select .bp-popup.bp-has-list > ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 5px 2px;
    max-height: 250px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Image is edited, I changed dropdown list to simple text input in my previous code structure to make it more readable, problem is still the same. 
[image]

Image showing dropdown list component, which works fine

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a sample project?

Comment: I will try to create some sample of it

Comment: Ok so I recreated sample project where you can clearly see it. I didnt add styles from my project, since we are using AdminLTE template. Just click on multiselect and you will see how those inputs overlay multiselect content list, however for dropdown its fine.  You can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1cUMZUfg03ATzNqdVJzM2poYmM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bootstrap compatibility issue. The `form-group` with `MultiSelect` is not focusable and therefore has lower `z-index` than the other groups.

Comment: So there is no solution for this right now and I have to find workaround

Comment: Yes. Bootstrap sets `z-index` to `3` for `.form-group:focus`. You can try to do the same for `.form-group.bp-state-focused`.